# Changing dropdown selected item in jquery not changing text?

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist and I am trying to change the selected item but the text is not changing. I am assuming it's because I am doing it client side but I once I've changed the selected item I am un sure how to change the text in the dropdownlist.

JQuery Code: -

```html
            function setPhotoStage(photoStageId) {
                $("[id*=drpPhotoStages] option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == photoStageId) {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                        alert($(this).val());
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
                    }
                });
            }
```

The code above is selecting the correct item in the list if I click on it but not changing it on the form: -
[image]

Here is the code when I inspect the dropdown. Some how I need to change the filter-option-inner-inner to the newly selected text: -

[image]

Any help please, I've looked everywhere and cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to sort it by adding refresh to the dropdown: -

```html
function setPhotoStage(photoStageId) {
                $("[id*=drpPhotoStages] option").each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == photoStageId) {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeAttr('selected');
                    }
                });
                $("#drpPhotoStages").selectpicker('refresh');
            }
```